# SSL Termination at F5 or ZUUl/Eureka/Services?

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, f5

We have a few services running in our environment with Spring Cloud Netflix, Eureka and Zuul. Also, we use Spring Boot for developing the services.

We also F5 as the hardware load balancer which receives the external requests and routes them to one of ZUUL instances based on the configured rule.

As of now, we use HTTP for communication between the services. We now want to secure all communications via HTTPS.

All the services including ZUUL and Eureka are scaled up with 2 instances in separate machines for failover.

My question is should I setup and enable HTTPS for each of the services including Eureka,ZUUL ad other downstream services (OR) Is it possible to only use HTTPS only for the F5. and leave the other instances in HTTP itself.

I heard of a feature called SSL Termination/off-loading which is provided by most load balancers. I am not sure F5 support it. If it supports would it make sense to only use it for HTTPS and leave the rest in HTTP.

I feel this can reduce the complexity in setting up SSL for each of the instances(which can change in the future based on the load) and also reduce the slowness which will be inherent with SSL decryption and encryption.

Should I secure every instance including eureka/zuul and downstream services or just do ssl-termination at F5 alone.

Comment: Yes, F5 can offload SSL and does it very well (full disclosure: I work for F5.) You can do a full offload and pass in the clear to your services, or you can offload to inspect for delivery or security services, then re-encyrpt and pass back to your backend services. Very flexible and can be configured to meet your business and security requirements in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 1):

If the back end endpoints are HTTPS then the load balancers need to load balance at TCP layer, as they cannot inspect the content. If the load balancer endpoints are HTTPS themselves, then there is usually little point of encrypting the internal traffic, and the load balancer can inspect the traffic and do smart decisions where to route the traffic (eg. sticky session). If the application endpoint needs to know that the original request is HTTPS (which is often the case) then a HTTP header is added to the internal leg to advertise this, the de-facto convention being the [X-FORWARDED-PROTO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) header.

If you choose to let the LB-to-app leg on clear, then you need to make sure that the segment is trustworthy and your app endpoints are not reachable directly, bypassing the LB.